Azure Logic App - Read secrets information from Azure Key Vault to authenticate blob connector
I have to create a workflow using standard Azure Logic App.
I am trying to authenticate Azure BLOB connector using connection string. One of the easiest way is to add connection string directly but manual intervention is required whenever there is a change in key and also it is not a secured way to authenticate any connector.
Another approach is to use the secrets from key vault. I created a parameter after adding secret in application setting but I am getting error. I read Microsoft documentation but haven't find any workaround to use secrets to authenticate connectors.

I have added new app setting variable
@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://keyVault.vault.azure.net/secrets/adlsgen2-key/)

Define parameter as -
{
    "BLOB": {
        "type": "String",
        "value": "@appsetting('ADLS-Gen2')"
    }
}

Used this parameter in connector for authentication -
@parameters('BLOB')

getting error message -

Encountered internal server error. The tracking Id is
'90762e8c-a5a9-4c75-be48-8446cef83c98'.


Need help to understand how to use secrets to authenticate connectors.
Thanks in advance.

So what’s the error? Have you configured the RBAC for the managed identity?

Added code snippets and error message

refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/572062/get-azure-blob-storage-account-key-from-azure-key, looks like its not supported yet

are you deploying the logic app using arm template?

Assuming that the question is about the Connections JSON (please provide its code if it still doesn't work) of your Standard Logic App, I have just created an answer.

Instead of using parameters (such as @parameters('BLOB')) in your connections.json file, please try using application settings (such as @appsetting('ADLS-Gen2')) directly.

This is an example from my own project.  Use @appsetting into of @parameters.  You need to point straight to the appsetting.
{
  "serviceProviderConnections": {
    "sql": {
      "parameterValues": {
        "connectionString": "@appsetting('SqlConnectionString')"
      },
      "parameterSetName": "connectionString",
      "serviceProvider": {
        "id": "/serviceProviders/sql"
      },
      "displayName": "pca-dw"
    },
    "AzureBlob": {
      "parameterValues": {
        "connectionString": "@appsetting('AzureStorageConnectionString')"
      },
      "parameterSetName": "connectionString",
      "serviceProvider": {
        "id": "/serviceProviders/AzureBlob"
      },
      "displayName": "lsl-storage-blob"
    }
  },
  "managedApiConnections": {}
}

